# How can I verify that all related fields in a Django REST Framework serializer specify objects with the same owner?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-organizations

I have a Django app that uses `django-organizations` for supporting shared accounts, and `rest_framework` for an API. I have a custom model for authentication that relates the user to an API token specific to an organization.

I have a model with a few foreign keys, a serializer with related fields, and a ModelViewSet for the API views. I want to make sure that any API calls for creating or modifying instances of my model verify that the objects specified for the related fields have the same owner (organization).

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(
        Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Foo(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(
        Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bar = models.ForeignKey(
        Bar, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('uuid', 'organization', 'bar')

    bar = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='uuid', queryset=Bar.objects.all())
```

How can I verify that related objects belong to the same account? Ideally, I'd be able to override the queryset specified for each `RelatedField` in the serializer, but I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Well you can override the `validate` method of your FooSerializer and raise a ValidationError if the organization of `’bar’` is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways come to mind - you can do w/validation on the ModelSerializer, but you would have to then pass the request into a serializer. My gut says it probably makes more sense on the Viewset. That way, if it's accessing something that it shouldn't have access to it returns a 404 (less information leakage).

To have this on the viewset, define get_queryset w/

```
def get_queryset(self)
    qs = MODEL.objects.filter(relation__user=self.request.user)
    return qs
```

More examples below :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset